# BigQuery - inventory balance calculation on an ad-hoc basis

Tags: google-bigquery, inventory-management

I have an inventory transaction BigQuery table as follows (apologies for not being able to post images).

The balance calculation is required periodically and is part of the table.

[Existing Data Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2V1K.png)

Expected result is an additional column containing stock balance on the day the calculation is done.

[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmRNT.png)

Thanks in advance for any thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

I think a better table structure is to have the stock balance as part of your default columns and just add another one that will hold the date/ timestamps of the period it was calculated.

| stock_balance | date_time_calculated |
| --- | --- |
| 0 |  |
| 3 | 2023-08-01 00:05:01 |
| 0 |  |
| 4 | 2023-09-01 22:30:41 |
| 0 |  |

What will happen is, whenever a calculation is made, the system will record its date/ timestamp. I believe this method needs lesser codes/ queries to write and will allow you to track the periods of your calculations.